# Как разделить компоненту React на блок и элемент

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, бэм

У меня возник вопрос. Если в БЭМ мы можем сделать блок как блок и как элемент задав в классе что то типа этого:

```
<div class="block_elem newBlock"></div>
```

То как можно это перенести на компоненту React?

```
<NewBlock />
```

Он по сути уже является блоком, но как его сделать одновременно элементом, что бы давать отступы не блоку , а элементу.
При этом использовать css-modules.

Я пришёл к выводу что приходится оборачивать компоненту ещё одним слоем...

```
<div calss="block_elem"><NewBlock /></div>
```

Comment: `<NewBlock /> ` вероятно возвращает какой-то jsx, так почему бы не навешивать классы на элементы, которые внутри `<NewBlock />` ?

Comment: Так я ж написал, что используя css modules, а там каждый css имеет свою локальную область, и подключать css модуль одного блока к другому не имеет смысла.

Comment: а что мешает создать отдельный css-модуль для `<NewBlock />`?

Comment: Ещё раз объясняю, у меня есть блок, у него ЕСТЬ модуль, я хочу сделать так, что бы он не влиял на окружение, а для этого нужно навешивать стили снаружи компонента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пришел к логическому выводу, что можно же передать компоненте props :

```
<NewBlock className={style.property} />
```

И записать его в класс в самой реализации :

```
function NewBlock(props) {
  <div className={style.property + " " + props.className}></div>
}
```